# Angularjs- Disable option in ng-option if already selected in adjacent select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time

I have a table where there are 2 select options which are dynamic

```
<tr>
     <th>Start time</th>
     <th>End time</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="s in config.time">
     <td>
       <select ng-model="s.start_time" class="form-control" ng-options="option for option in config.hrs"></select>
     </td>
     <td>
       <select ng-model="s.end_time" class="form-control" ng-options="option for option in config.hrs"></select>
     </td>
</tr>
```

value in `config.hrs` is also dynamic which holds the hours in an array.

```
hrs = ["00:00","00:30","01:00",..,"23:00","23:30"]
```

I want to disable the hour which is selected in start_time from being selected as end_time and if i add another row i dont want the previously selected hrs to be enabled.

I tried to disable like this
    `<select ng-model="s.end_time" class="form-control" ng-options="option disable when s.start_time for option in config.hrs"></select>`
but it disables the entire options in end_time.

Image 1 is my current output.[image]

Image 2 is my expected output. [image]

Comment: If you can create a code snippet or fiddle that will be great, else you can use ng-change where you can call some function and set your logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to do this with your current setup.

#### Alternative #1

Hold an array of objects, e.g. `[{ time: '08:00', selected: false }, ...]`. Then you can display only options where `selected === false`, although not with `ng-options`, but with a simple `ng-repeat` on `<option>...</option>`.

#### Alternative #2

On select remove the selected time from an array and store it in another variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this type of code-

```
    <td>
       <select ng-model="s.end_time" class="form-control">
        <option ng-repeat="option in config.hrs" ng-disabled="s.start_time > option" >{{option}}</option>
       </select>
     </td>
```

Hope it will give you an idea and help you to resolve the issue.